# Uncaught RangeError: and too much recursion

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I am trying to get my form to work. I have two errors I am getting and can't figure out where exactly they are happening. The first one is:

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
e.extend.each
$.extend.ready
$.extend.ready
$.extend.ready... //there are literally 50+ more $.extend.ready scripts below this
```

This error has to deal with the jquery file as I deleted the other two to find out where it came from and the error disappeared when I deleted the jquery file. The file is jquery-1.7.1min.js. I can't use a later edition for purposes out of my control.

and the second one is:

too much recursion:

```
if ($.browser.mozilla || $.browser.opera) {
document.removeEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", $.ready, false);...//the first line basically
```

I did a search on both of course but the problems don't seem to relate to whatever error is in my script. I have a form I am trying to get to run and I feel these two issues are probably causing the problem. The "clear" and "submit" buttons aren't working so trying to knock out the problems I know, and these are the last two that I have.

OK I found where an issue was:

```
$(function () { //this is the way to run your code at the DOM Ready event

    $('a').click(function () {
        $('html, body').animate({  //this is line 8
            scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top
        }, 1500);
        return false;
    });

});
```

> SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'top' of undefined or null reference 
>   script.js, line 8 character 9

what could this be then?

Comment: It seems unlikely that merely including the jQuery file in your page generates the error. How does your code make use of the library?

Comment: Both are related to something looping somewhere, probably forever, adding to the stack until it reaches it's limit, and the "too much recursion" error appears. It's not jQuery, but something you did, that is the problem.

Comment: the problem is the error goes away with the jquery file. I only have 2 other javascript files in the project (although one is extremely long) I can't seem to find the problem with a debugging tool so how can I figure out how to find what is repeating?

Comment: Any code reliant on jQuery will not run when you remove jQuery, that's why the problem dissapears, not because jQuery is the cause of the problem.

Comment: I can see two routes you could take to diagnose this: 1) Start commenting out your jQuery code until the problem goes away and narrow down the issue. 2) Use the javascript profiler in your browser to see if you can find the problem.

Comment: Since it's an infinite loop, this should not be too hard to find with a debugger. You have literally infinite tries to detect the code causing the loop. Just step strough the code line by line, and at some point you should say "Ah, I was here before" ;)

Comment: @Keith see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17790530/uncaught-rangeerror-and-too-much-recursion#comment25954675_17790530

Comment: did you mean to reference your answer below or another question?

Comment: It's a link that points to itself - infinite recursion ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If your `href` attribute is pointing at a named anchor (e.g. `<a name="foo">`) that uses the `name` attribute then you cannot use `#foo` to resolve it, because `#` in a selector matches the *`id`* attribute, not the *`name`* attribute.

In your case, since `#foo` doesn't exist, `$('#foo').offset()` will produce an empty object with no `.top` property.

You could:

1. Use an `id` attribute instead of `name` on the anchor, or
2. use the `$([name=...])` selector (having stripped off the leading `#`), or
3. store some other meta-data with the `.data()` function to point at the desired element.

Comment: the problem is it is referencing this line $('html').animate({  not this line  scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top . I switched out the names to see if it worked and it's still referencing that top line as the problem, not the id name.

Comment: @Keith that's not what the error you reported above says - it clearly says that `.top` cannot be resolved, which means that `.offset()` is an empty object, which means that the selector before that is empty.

Comment: I apologize, someone edited out the reference to what line 8 was. Please see above now. Unless it is just referencing to the start of the function

Comment: If the rest of the error message is as described (i.e. about `.top`) then ignore the line number.

Comment: ok, another way then. I deleted .top just to see what that would do and it resets the page I believe, else is clears the form. I am understanding what you are saying but it isn't working. So if .top is a function that resets to the top of the page, what can I put in place of that to keep it there? I have return false; already and that doesn't do the trick.